# Data in the store is restarting after routing to a different page in state management Akita

Tags: angular, state-management, angular-akita

After updating the store and routing to another page,
the information that I sent to the store was restated,
as you can see the flow is @@INIT twice and not and I don't understand why?

- angular 13
- the component that I routing has a different module,
- I am using changeDetection

[image]

Comment: So where do you dispatch INIT and are you navigating correctly using routerlink?

Comment: Thanks to your comment, I changed it from navigation from navigating from ts.file  to routerlink in html, and now it is working, Thanks :)